# How to test for improper use of expr == on strings?

Tags: tcl

Using `==` in `expr` can lead to unintended behavior for strings that also qualify as doubles. One example being `if {$a == $b}` when a=1.0 and b=1. I imagine the reason `==` even works for strings post 8.4 is backwards compatibility with scripts that haven't replaced it with `eq` yet.

Is there a (simple) way to detect this at runtime, possibly finding all erroneous uses during test? Like activating a "strict" mode or something?

Comment: There can't be such a check, because Tcl doesn't have types. So who's to say the developer didn't actually want to compare the numbers as floating point values?

Comment: @SchelteBron I want something similar to `error` if using `==` to compare operands for which `string is double -strict` returns `false`. There is no ambiguity in intent; using `==` for non-double class operands is always wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl, by *design,* has no such simple way to check. (In 8.6 onwards, there's an unsupported command, `tcl::unsupported::representation`, which can do part of the check, but it doesn't really do what you want, especially with literals.) The real issue is that in the logical type-system of Tcl, strings are a supertype of all other value types and all other value types are thus serializable as strings and that's guaranteed to work (provided you have enough memory).

But there are ways to enforce numeric-ness by doing operations which require numbers, and the simplest is probably to just add the unary `+` in front of the arguments:

```
if {+$x == +$y} { ...
```

Enforcing integer-ness can be done with `$x | 0` or `$x ^ 0`. There's not usually any need to enforce floating-point-ness as distinct from numeric-ness. If you really need it, `string is` has the various checks you need but they're probably going to be expensive.

---

All the above work in all versions of Tcl from this millennium, except where explicitly noted.

Comment: I'd bet that the `+` operator is in Tcl because it is in C; Tcl's original operator set was stolen from there except for the ones that were obviously unsafe (such as the pointer-related ones). It just happens that the _use_ of `+` in Tcl is totally different to in C.

Comment: The [Nagelfar checker](http://nagelfar.sourceforge.net/index.html) might help with this too. Or might not.

Comment: I see. Feared as much. Gonna try Nagelfar out. Could help finding other problems.

Answer (score 1):

The operators known in Tcl (except &&, ||, and ? :) are available in the tcl::mathop namespace. Unfortunately, contrary to functions in the tcl::mathfunc namespace, redefining tcl::mathop::== has no effect on the way `expr` treats '=='.

I'm afraid the only way to do what you're asking, short of changing the Tcl C code, would be to redefine `expr` and other commands that take arithmetic expressions as arguments (if, for, while). Parse the expression arguments, splitting it in parts on either side of the ==, while taking order of precedence into account. Then pass each part through the original `expr` and check if the results fulfill `string is double -strict`.

This is not a trivial exercise and will probably also considerably slow down the execution of your script.

Comment: If you want to go ahead and modify the Tcl C code, it looks to me like the place to do that is tclExecute.c around line 6089 (for Tcl 8.6.10).